# Can '~/.local/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css' have priority over '/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css'?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, css

The `ubuntu.css` file is found in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`. I would like to customise this file. Thereafter, should I replace the original with this customised file (I see this practise on-line) or should I store the customised file to `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`. I am thinking that it should take priority over `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`. Also, I can avoid interfering with sudo permission level files. Is this thought process correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard local directories are `~/.themes` or `~/.local/share/themes`. You can copy your theme folder to one of these directories and modify the files. But it won't override the default GNOME Shell theme, you need to use the '[User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/)' GNOME shell extension. Then you would be able to activate your modified theme using *GNOME Tweaks* for example.

Note that the correct location for the `.css` file is as follows:
`~/.themes/<ThemeName>/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` or
`~/.local/share/themes/<ThemeName>/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`.

So copy the `ubuntu.css` file to, for example, `~/.themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/` and rename it as `gnome-shell.css` (you may also have to copy some or all other files in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` to `~/.themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/` too in this case).

You should be able to activate "MyCustomTheme" as the GNOME Shell theme after activating the User Themes extension.

Comment: As a try, I copied everything in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` to   `~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/`. Did Alt+F2 followed by r+Return. But I could not see the theme "MyCustomTheme" in GNOME Tweaks -->Appearance -->Application to select it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It won't appear as an "Application" theme, it's for the "Shell" theme. Also as I mentioned before you need to enable the User Themes extension first in order to be able to load a Shell theme from a local directory.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It worked. Am I correct to think that ~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css is used by both GNOME Tweaks -->Appearance -->Application and GNOME Tweaks -->Appearance -->Shell ?

Comment: No, "Application" theme is dictated by other components like gtk2, gtk3 etc. Since you just copied only components of the default Shell theme and there no other folders in `~/.local/share/themes/MyCustomTheme/` except `gnome-shell`, it won't work as a valid Application theme..